# Stuck in a boot loop

Tags: boot, boot-repair

I have a Lenovo B575. I took the hard drive out of an Asus laptop and put it in this one with the intention of reformatting the drive and installing Ubuntu as a new OS. That was my intent. I can get it past the Lenovo splash, after which it says "Booting in insecure mode" after that an error flashed for about a tenth of a second and all I can read is failure to ___ PXE I've included the pastebin from my boot repair below

http://paste.ubuntu.com/11944488/

Comment: I should also add that I have no idea what I'm doing, so please be patient.